How can one properly add and validate choices using l3keys?
Greetings... again!
Yesterday, I posted a question here about how to manage the options passed to a custom class. I was directed to a thread within this community that helped clarify my question. However, a new issue has arisen: How can one properly add and validate choices with l3keys?
Let’s say I want to pass an option called school to my custom class, and within this option, I want to only accept the values a, b, and c. If any value other than these is passed, a warning should be issued, and the default value for school should be a. How can I properly achieve this with l3keys or another suitable package?
So far, I’ve tried two approaches. In the first one, I simply declare the key, and if no option is provided, a default value is applied using a set key.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myc}

\DeclareKeys{
    school.store = \school
}

\SetKeys{
    school = a
}

\ProcessKeyOptions

\LoadClass{minimal} 

The second approach I tried involved experimenting with techniques I found in the clsguide and interface3 documentation.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { myc } {
    school .choice:,
    school / a .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \myschool { a } },
    school / b .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \myschool { b } },
    school / c .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \myschool { c } },
    school .default:n = { a },
}

\msg_new:nnn { myc } { invalid-school } {
    Invalid school option '#1'. Allowed options are 'a', 'b', and 'c'.
}

\keys_set_known:nn { myc } { school }
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler {
    \msg_error:nnx { myc } { invalid-school } { #1 }
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \typeout{School: \myschool}
}

\ProcessKeysOptions { myc }

\ExplSyntaxOff

The first scenario works, but it doesn’t include the specific choices I want. The second scenario, however, simply doesn’t work.
What can I do to make it function as expected? Thank you in advance, and I apologise for any confusion — I’m fairly new to this topic.

Please say more than it "simply doesn't work". Specifically describe the error you get or the unexpected result. Also, \ProcessKeysOptions is from the deprecated l3keys2e package. Current documents should use the kernel command \ProcessKeyOptions[<module>]. If your clsguide still shows \ProcessKeysOptions then you need to update your distribution

Several things to note.

If your class is written entirely in expl3, you can use \ProvidesExplClass to avoid having to write \ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff.
For your use case, the .choices:nn handler is easier than .choice:.
Use the .initial:n handler to set initial values while defining keys instead of calling \keys_set:nn later.
Most x-type arguments were deprecated in favor of e-type. Same for \ProcessKeysOptions which is defined by the deprecated package l3keys2e. Use \ProcessKeyOptions instead. These things suggest your TeX distribution could use an update.
If using expl3, use proper naming conventions. So a global tl variable should be of the form \g_<module>_<submodule>_<name>_tl. For this simple example I've omitted using a submodule.
Don't load the minimal class. It is a common and understandable mistake to think it's good for simple examples, but it's too simple for most things and can hide issues. Use article for examples.
If you want to pass unknown options to the article class, add

\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler
  {
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
  }

Here's how I'd implement your class.
myc.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\ProvidesExplClass{myc}{2024/11/30}{0.1}{some description}
\keys_define:nn { myc } {
    school .choices:nn =
      { a, b, c }
      { \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_myc_myschool_tl \l_keys_value_tl },
    school / unknown .code:n =
      {
        \msg_error:nne { myc } { invalid-school } { #1 }
      },
    school .default:n = { a },
    school .initial:n = { a },
}
\msg_new:nnn { myc } { invalid-school }
  {
    Invalid~school~option~'#1'.~
    Allowed~options~are~'a',~'b',~and~'c'.
  }
\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \iow_log:e { School:~\g_myc_myschool_tl }
  }
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler
  {
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions[myc]
\LoadClass{article}

If you prefer a warning to an error, you can replace \msg_error:nne with \msg_warning:nne.
test.tex
You can give options like a4paper which are passed to the article class.
\documentclass[a4paper,school=b]{myc}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}

The log shows
School: b

Just
\documentclass{myc}

shows
School: a

And if you give a value besides a, b, or c, you get an error.
\documentclass[school=blub]{myc}

results in the error
! Package myc Error: Invalid school option 'blub'. Allowed options are 'a',
(myc)                'b', and 'c'.


It works perfectly! I really appreciate the detailed explanations in your answer, as well as the initial comment you provided for the question above. Once again, thank you!

@cfr date requirement added

@Skillmon Thanks, added

@mbert sorry, mistyped from the top of my head, it's called \msg_warning:nne (I corrected that)
